# Tab Apps - signed_request

Tags: facebook

I have 2 FB profiles, one is a dev user that I develop apps with and the other my normal FB account.

I created a FB app with the dev user and linked it to a tab.

With my dev user when I view the tab and echo out the decoded signed_request i get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [expires] => 1317124800
    [issued_at] => 1317118449
    [oauth_token] =>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [page] => Array
        (
            [id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            [liked] => 
            [admin] => 1
        )
    [user] => Array
        (
            [country] => xxxxxx
            [locale] => en_US
            [age] => Array
                (
                    [min] => 21
                )
        )
    [user_id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
)
```

However when I setup my main user as an admin and then test the app my output looks like this:

```
Array ( [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256 [issued_at] => 1317118842 [page] => Array ( [id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [liked] => [admin] => 1 ) [user] => Array ( [country] => za [locale] => en_US [age] => Array ( [min] => 21 ) ) )
```

You can see that that my **[oauth_token], [expires]** have been left out.

How can this be and what am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Phil

Comment: WOOP WOOP !!!!! Its working thanx meneer....

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the second user hasn't authorised the app. The API will only pass UID, tokens & expires for TOS'd users.

Answer (score 0):

A user MUST interact with a tab before it is given an oauth_token. This is why you have no [user_id] on the second print_r.